# Android TelephonyManager getCelllLocation, getting deprecated?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

As per Android doc, it says `getCellLocation API` call will be deprecated in future. Does anyone have an idea why it is getting deprecated? 
If this is deprecating then, is there any other alternative to get Cell Location information?

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCellLocation%28%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement method will be [`TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo()).

From the description in the documentation:

> This method is preferred over using **getCellLocation()**. However, for
>   older devices, **getAllCellInfo()** may return null. In these cases, you
>   should call **getCellLocation()** instead.

Comment: According to docs "This method was deprecated in API level 26". I had to double check this https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers API level 26 is currently the next API to be yet released; is Android "O". Not using deprecated code is an important good practice but this scenario is so skew that I tend to think that is not something to worry about.

Comment: It is nowhere in the docs  "This method is preferred over using getCellLocation(). However, for older devices, getAllCellInfo() may return null. In these cases, you should call getCellLocation() instead." I think your answer need to be updated.